# How to add/change NAPTR records to a specific ZoneScope in Windows DNS using PowersShell

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, powershell

I'm using DNS Policies in Windows DNS for split-horizon. I need to add NAPTR records which resolve differently based on the subnet of where the request came from. I've got almost all of it figured out, but I can't figure out how to add NAPTR records. (It works just fine with A records.)

These can be easily managed in the DNS GUI, but there is no method for using the GUI to add resource records to zone scopes.

[image: Sample NAPTR record]

It should be some variation of Add-DnsServerResourceRecord, and Microsoft's documentation suggests it should work with NAPTR (which is Service number 35) but I've searched the Internet high and low and can't find an answer.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, what's the purpose of these NAPTR records in your environment?

Comment: Component of a Next-Gen 911 system. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5222#page-6